# Accessing a DOM object defined in an external SVG file

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

SVG standard allows to use and refer external SVG files.

I have a file `circle.svg` that defines a circle object with id "the_circle".
From the main SVG file I am able to include this circle and animate it, using [SVG linking](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html).

I would also like to access the same circle object via javascript, how can I do this ?
What is the javascript equivalent of `xlink:href="url(#the_image)#the_circle"` ?

Using `document.getElementById('the_image')` I can only access the SVGImageElement but not the objects defined inside the included  SVG.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

  <image 
    id="the_image"
    x="0" y="0"  width="100%" height="100%"
    xlink:href="circle.svg" />

  <animateTransform     
    xlink:href="url(#the_image)#the_circle"

    attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
    type="translate" 
    from="0" to="25"
    dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" 
    additive="replace" fill="freeze" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Posted the same question at svg-developers http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/message/63940

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like the "right" way to do this would actually be to use an SVG "use" element, rather than an image. The reason for this is that the DOM interface of the SVG use element specifies a property "instanceRoot", which allows you to get the root of the "instance tree" corresponding to that use element: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceSVGUseElement

So, you would end up with a solution that looks something like the following:
circle.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="4in" height="4in" id="the_svg"
     viewBox="0 0 4 4" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle r="1" fill="blue" stroke="none" id="the_circle"/>
</svg>
```

Document which uses the svg root node of circle.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" id="foo"
     version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 

    <use xlink:href="circle.svg#the_svg"/>
</svg>
```

Unfortunately, though, while Firefox supports use of the use element with external documents, there's currently a bug in Webkit which does not allow this: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12499

Also, Firefox does not seem to implement the instanceRoot property for use elements.

So, it seems you may need to work around the limitations of current SVG implementations. The way I would recommend doing this is to use XMLHttpRequest to download the document to which you would like to link, and import the DOM of the downloaded document into your host document's DOM. The following code implements this, and works in Firefox, Opera and Chromium:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" id="foo"
     version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 

    <script>
    function fetchXML  (url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function (evt) {
        //Do not explicitly handle errors, those should be
        //visible via console output in the browser.
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            callback(xhr.responseXML);
        }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    };

    //fetch the document
    fetchXML("http://localhost:8082/tmp/circle.svg",function(newSVGDoc){
        //import it into the current DOM
        var n = document.importNode(newSVGDoc.documentElement,true);
        document.documentElement.appendChild(n);

        var circle = document.getElementById("the_circle"); //now you have the circle
    }) 
    </script>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Other attempts to fetch the SVG via XHR and append it to the DOM didn't succeed. Thanks!

Comment: hey jbeard4 :)
I was trying to use your solution for a big SVG (900kb) and now the Code load before the SVG is loded and then i cant access the svg. here is the link to my question  [My Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682214/cant-access-svg-by-its-id) i think you can help me !

Comment: The [referenced bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12499) was fixed in 2012 in Firefox.

Answer (score 13):

You can access the necessary element a bit easier:

```
document.getElementById('the_image').contentDocument.getElementById('the_circle')
```

See  [this image](http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/22/html2svg.png) for reference (taken on [dev.opera.com](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/svg-evolution-not-revolution/?page=2))
[image]

Comment: Nice, but what's the catch?  I assume this only works on SVGs included from the same domain?

Comment: And so what? Generally you want to manipulate your file, not a one from some other site.

Comment: I'll take that as a yes; just good to be clear.  I agree that same-domain is very often the case, making the other answers rather overkill unless a general solution really is needed.

Comment: Actually making ajax requests to another domain faces the same issue, unless it allows CORS.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for `file://` URLs either. Rather annoying.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement @echo-flow's excellent solution with the code in jQuery/Coffeescript:

```
  $.get '/assets/hexagon.svg', (svgFileData)->
    svgTag = svgFileData.documentElement
    $('body').append(svgTag)
    circle = $('#the_circle')
```

Comment: Don't forget to import the node using document.importNode. It might complain if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to this problem when using React and ES6.  Usage:

```
<SvgImage url='pathToImage.svg'></SvgImage>
```

https://gist.github.com/mikkel/8b79a713ff06bbec379d