# Transfer of part of a DOM or SVG structure from server to client browser

Tags: security, html, dom, svg, d3.js

I recently embarked on a highly interactive html5 application using d3.js and svg.

Though currently running entirely in the browser, I've taken care to separate code used to **generate** the svg structures from that **manipulating** them.

To protect at least the svg generation logic (by far the greater effort), I'm toying with the idea of it's server-side generation using node.js, somehow "clipping" the resulting DOM or SVG structure, passing this to the browser and effectively "grafting" it onto (respectively) the local DOM **or** a prepared html div. The goals:

1. none of the original "svg-generating" javascript would be transferred
2. any resulting structure should ultimately be addressable using d3's select() or selectAll() calls

I have **no** node.js and only vague html5 DOM knowledge. My questions:

- Is transfer of part of a raw DOM or SVG structure to the browser feasible, and how?
- If both possible, which would you recommend
- Are there specific security issues I should be aware of

I realise this is a potentially complex issue, welcome partial answers and relevant leads (books, tuturials, examples).

Though I searched intensively before posting this question, I missed 
[Accessing a DOM object defined in an external SVG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346106/accessing-a-dom-object-defined-in-an-external-svg-file). Looks promising, but given the size and complexity of the structures I need to transfer, I'd welcome further comment.

Thanks

Comment: Why protect logic, it's a waste of time.

Comment: Here's why. The logic in question generates a hierarchy comprising thousands of svg objects. I'm aware the accepted wisdom, am enthusiastic as the next about open source, but also unemployed and over 55. The more difficult I make a plagiarist's life, the better the chances my family don't go hungry, and WTH, the time wasted is only my own, right? Let's both hope that I can bring it to a point where I too can relax on this.

Comment: Why do you think this would be any different to regular [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)?

Comment: @user1019696 I didn't say make it open source. What I meant to say was think carefully about whether you favor "user experience" or "code protection". If the code belongs on a server, put it there. If it belongs on the client, put it there. Deal with code theft like everyone else does, through legal avenues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Is transfer of part of a raw DOM or SVG structure to the browser feasible, and how?*

   Yes, it is possible. Simply transfer any particular sub-node/tree of the SVG as its own XML document.
2. *If both possible, which would you recommend*

   HTTP communication is all strings, so you can't pass 'DOM' objects over the network. All you can pass are the serialized versions (the raw SVG XML).
3. *Are there specific security issues I should be aware of*

   None that I can think of. This seems like standard server-side generation of content. What sort of issues were you thinking about? You're not going to execute raw code sent in the HTTP request on your server, are you?

Comment: Thanks, Phrogz, no: there is not raw code being sent. My concerns related more to (the possibility of) DOM-clipping transfer.