# Can't access SVG by its ID

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, get, load

I want to access the id of the svg and its paths after the file has loaded for interactive use. I load the SVG with a function and import the node to the DOM. Neither in *document.ready* nor in *document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event)* i am able to get the element by its id. The only way to get it is to set a timeout around the interactive code.

What i want is that the SVG (900kb) und its DOM should load before all other code is loaded. But until now i couldn find a fiting solution.

I am very confused because if i look at the DOM in the browser with firebug i am able to see the div with the ID but i cant get it .... And i cant find a issue in my code because i load it in the DOM and access it after DOM is ready ?
Anyone here who find a solution?

This is my code to load the svg:

```
function fetchXML  (url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function (evt) {

        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            callback(xhr.responseXML);          
        }

        };
        xhr.send(null);
    };

    fetchXML("svg/bez_grey.svg",function(newSVGDoc){
        var n = document.importNode(newSVGDoc.documentElement,true);
        var mysvg = document.getElementById("map"); 

        mysvg.appendChild(n);

    })  

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

// Access the SVG-Elements here 

}):
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `document.documentElement.appendChild(n);` before calling `var mysvg = document.getElementById("map");`. This loads `n` into `document`'s DOM. You can delete statement `mysvg.appendChild(n);`

This solution is based on working code example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3378320