# How to access an svg inner id and have CSS change the fill color of that id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

This is my svg file

next.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>

<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
 <g class="next">
  <g>
   <polygon fill="#FFD92D" class="inner" points="20.587,5.055 78.706,48 20.587,90.945"/>
   <path fill="#FF9900" class="outer" d="M21.623,7.11L76.961,48L21.623,88.89V7.11 M19.55,3v90l60.9-45L19.55,3L19.55,3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

This is my basic html to display the svg

```
<div>
    <object id="objsvg" class="svgbtn" type="image/svg+xml" data="next.svg" onclick="changeSVGColor()"></object>    
</div>
```

This is my style.css file

```
.inner {
  fill: #000000;
}
.inner-new-color {
    fill: #ff00ff;
}
```

This is my basic jQuery to change the color of .inner in svg file. What am I doing wrong?

It does not even seem like the #objsvg selector has the inner class at all, since $("#objsvg").hasClass("inner")); returns false.

```
function changeSVGColor() {
    $("#objsvg").removeClass("inner");
    $("#objsvg").addClass("inner-new-color");
}
```

Comment: Check my [SVG solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002310/best-practice-for-using-svg-images/25032941#25032941) on embedded and reuse that coding. Then update SVG part and tweak the coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the portion you want to change by class. `$(".inner")`

```
$(".inner").removeClass("inner").addClass("inner-new-color");
```

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Reedpm2/5bz94d0p/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the Fiddle. Is there a way to do this using the <object> tag with an external svg file instead of the <svg> tag? I am able to access the ".inner" class when the svg is inline, but having trouble accessing it when the svg is in a separate file.

Comment: I am not entirely positive on how to do it from an external svg file. You may want to check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31129363/5774702) from another thread. He gives a few options and links to examples. Hopefully something there can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am going to accept this answer as it has gotten me the closest to solving this.

Answer (score 0):

The ID will not work on the parent or 'object', you will need to open your SVG with something like sublime text, and add an `id="objsvg"` for whatever path you are trying to manipulate.

e.g..

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
 <g class="next">
  <g>
   <polygon fill="#FFD92D" class="inner" points="20.587,5.055 78.706,48 20.587,90.945"/>
   <path id="objsvg" fill="#FF9900" class="outer" d="M21.623,7.11L76.961,48L21.623,88.89V7.11 M19.55,3v90l60.9-45L19.55,3L19.55,3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

see updated js fiddle, pop open your console too
[jsfiddle.net/xaLkvc27/12](http://jsfiddle.net/xaLkvc27/12)

Comment: I added the id="objsvg" to the svg file, but $("#objsvg").hasClass("outer")); returns false when running. Is there a way to access the svg element somehow using jQuery? This  $("#objsvg") I believe it getting me access to the object, but I am interested in getting the svg inside of the object using jQuery.

Comment: If you were getting false, make sure you added that ID to your HTML or SVG markup,  I have updated the jsfiddle, This should make this a bit more clear, lemme know if you have more questions  https://jsfiddle.net/xaLkvc27/12/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment and fiddle. I am trying to access the svg using the <object> tag and having the svg file in an external file and not inline. Is there a way to access the ".inner" and ".outer" class when the svg file is in an external file?