# SVG access layers in CSS but from file not HTML code

Tags: html, css, svg

I know if i add the hole SVG code in HTML i can access all the layers via CSS. But in this case i want to have my SVG as a separate file and then in HTML i'm linking to it. But is it possible to access the layers in CSS?

```
<div class="test"><img src="file.svg" /></div>
```

So i have tried this:

```
let poly_shapes = function myfunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("svg1");
var y = x.contentDocument.getElementById('clouds_1_');
return y;};
```

HTML i have:

```
<object id="svg1" data="pilis.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Before this if i had my svg code in html this JS would work

```
let poly_shapes = $('#clouds_1_')
```

Comment: You can't.....it's an SVG image not an actual SVG

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128970/how-do-you-style-a-external-svg-with-css?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Ok so i can see 2 solutions add the code to my CSS main file. or try JS : "You can grab a hold of the external images' tree with JavaScript and edit their styles from there. The keyword for that would be contentDocument, see this answer."

Comment: so i have tried JS version, i have left my update on top