# Can I get path length from SVG in Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, shadow-dom

I'm using a set of svg icons that get injected into the page from a separate file.

`<svg class="icon-home">
  <use xlink:href="symbol-defs.svg#icon-home"></use>
</svg>`

This loads the path into the shadow DOM. Is there any way that I can get the path length in order to do a 'drawing' animation, or am I going to have to rethink how I'm loading the svg into the DOM? I'm doing it this way because it is part of a page builder plugin and the user can select from a large number of icons.

Comment: Would it not be possible to retrieve this information from the symbol itself? What type of animation are you trying to accomplish and what is the content of the symbol?

Comment: While referencing external files in `<use>` nowadays works chross-browser, Firefox *still* does not support `SVGUseElement.instanceRoot`. Therefore, it seems the solution presented in [Accessing a DOM object defined in an external SVG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346106/accessing-a-dom-object-defined-in-an-external-svg-file/3378320#3378320) stills stands: load the icon via XHR.